# Why is my ArrayList Empty?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am working on Project Euler problem 13. ( https://projecteuler.net/problem=13 ) The file "Large_Num_List.txt" is the list provided by the project Euler with each number on its own line with a quote mark at the beginning and end of each line. The statement bial.isEmpty() returns true. Why is this happening? (I suspect because this is my first time using Scanner to read a text file.)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LargeSumTwo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    ArrayList<BigInteger> bial = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    File file = new File("Large_Num_List.txt");

    try 
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        while(scan.hasNextBigInteger()) 
        {
            bial.add((BigInteger) scan.nextBigInteger());
        }
        scan.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(bial.isEmpty());
    BigInteger answer = new BigInteger("0");
    Iterator<BigInteger> iter = bial.iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
      answer.add(iter.next());
    }

    System.out.println(answer);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is in your file?

Comment: A list of 100 50-digit numbers surrounded by the aforementioned quotes.

Comment: With such file content what do you expect `scan.hasNextBigInteger()` to return and why?

Comment: So just do scan.hasNext() ?

Comment: @Devereaux - The quotes are going to throw the `Scanner` off. The token will be `"23456"` which is definitely not a valid BigInteger. You'll have to read the file line by line, remove the quotes, and then try to parse the number that way.

Comment: Also, the line `answer.add(iter.next())` should be `answer = answer.add(iter.next())`.  `BigInteger.add()` returns a new BigInteger containing the sum, it doesn't update the object on which the method was invoked.

Comment: I have saved all numbers (no quotes)  and you program indicates that the bial is NOT empty. After fixing he sum error the program displays false, 5537376230390876637302048746832985971773659831892672

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the quotes first.  `hasNextBigInteger()` will only return `true` if `Scanner` can parse a `BigInteger`. The quotes around the numbers will cause `hasNextBigInteger()` to return `false`.

JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextBigInteger%28%29

Comment: In the link author has provided the numbers have no quotes (see link above)

Answer (score 1):

Should you add BigInteger in this way:

```
while(iter.hasNext())
{
  answer = answer.add(iter.next());
}
```

as BigDecimal numbers are immutable?